# Database connection spike

Tags: mysql, database, rds

I have built a springboot-2.1.2.RELEASE application. Have used spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE in the application which is using hikaricp by default. Have added the following properties

```
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME:root}

spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD:notarealpassword}

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${DB_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver}

spring.datasource.validationQuery=${DB_VALIDATION_QUERY:SELECT 1}

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=${DB_CONN_TEST_QUERY:SELECT 1}

spring.jpa.show-sql=${DB_SHOWSQL:false}

spring.jpa.format-sql=${DB_FORMATSQL:false}

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${DB_HIBERNATE_DIALECT:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect}

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=${HIKARI_CONN_TIMEOUT:30000}

spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=${HIKARI_IDLE_TIMEOUT:600000}

spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=${HIKARI_MAX_LIFETIME:1800000}
```

I have deployed my application in a kubernetes cluster in my company. For database, the application connects aws RDS. After starting my application, the database connection count increases abruptly. I am unable to RCA the DB connection leak.

PFA a screenshot of connection spike
[DB connection spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z14Dc.png)

After certain threshold, I have to stop the application but I am unable to debug the cause. This is happening even when application is not yet used. It starts to happens 5 minutes after the application is up. Is there any property necessary to setup for hikari other than what has been setup as per above. How should I debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Limit database connections each instance of the application will try to maintain.
2. If you can, restart your application servers after deploying new application server versions.
3. Limit connections on your AWS RDS instances *externally*, from a different system to the application server and the data base themselves, using  e.g. AWS Lambda devices which would kill excessive idle connections.

   1. Then you use this same device for killing excessively long lived queries ran from the application server, if applicable (most probably, yes).